# Java with GSON - deserialize only the values into an ArrayList of a JSON string

Tags: java, json, arraylist, deserialization, gson

I have this structure of my JSON response string:

```
{
    "1":{
        "data1":"1","data2":"test1", ...
    },
    "2":{
        "data1":"6","data2":"test2", ...
    },
    ...
}
```

And I want to get the *values* to put into an `ArrayList<MyItem>`. I use GSON and normally I can do it in this way:

```
ArrayList<MyItem> items = 
    gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyItem>>() {}.getType());
```

The problem is, that it does not work, because my JSON String has numbers as keys, but I only want to get the values to put into the `ArrayList` (unfortunately, the JSON string can not be changed by myself). How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Why not try to put the json into `Map<Integer, ArrayList<MyItem>> map` and afterwards `List<MyItems> map = foreach(..)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably deserialize the JSON into a `java.util.Map`, get the values from the `Map` as a `Collection` using [the `Map.values()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29), and then create a new `ArrayList` using [the constructor that takes a `Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29).

Comment: I did it this way. I thought, there is a better solution, but I also did not find one.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom deserializer.

```
class MyItem 
{
    String data1;
    String data2;
    // ...
}

class MyJSONList extends ArrayList<MyItem> {}

class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyJSONList> 
{
    public MyJSONList deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) 
        throws JsonParseException
    {
        MyJSONList list = new MyJSONList();
        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> e : je.getAsJsonObject().entrySet())
        {
            list.add((MyItem)jdc.deserialize(e.getValue(), MyItem.class));
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

Example:

```
String json = "{\"1\":{\"data1\":\"1\",\"data2\":\"test1\"},\"2\":{\"data1\":\"6\",\"data2\":\"test2\"}}";
Gson g = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(MyJSONList.class, new MyDeserializer())
            .create();
MyJSONList l = g.fromJson(json, MyJSONList.class);


for (MyItem i : l)
{
    System.out.println(i.data2);
}
```

Output:

> test1
> test2